# Writing to table using Javascript? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to write to a table using Javascript. I've been using document.getElementById("text").innerHTML but it isn't working. 
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

The program is supposed to 'roll' a dice 1000 times, counting how many of each number is rolled and then printing the results in a table.

I can get the Math.random function to work, and I can get count the number of times each number is rolled, but I can't seem to figure out how to get those numbers into the table at the end.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8"; http-equiv="Content-type">
<script type="text/javascript">
 var dice;

 var one = 0;
 var two = 0; 
 var three = 0;
 var four = 0; 
 var five = 0;
 var six = 0; 

 var i;

 for(i=1; i<=1000; i++) {

 dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
 
 if(dice==1) one++;
 else if(dice==2) two++;
 else if(dice==3) three++;
 else if(dice==4) four++;
 else if(dice==5) five++;
 else six++;

 } //end of for


 //write results to the table
  document.getElementById("r1").innerHTML = one;
 document.getElementById("r2").innerHTML = two;
 document.getElementById("r3").innerHTML = three;
 document.getElementById("r4").innerHTML = four;
 document.getElementById("r5").innerHTML = five;
 document.getElementById("r6").innerHTML = six;
 document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = i;


</script>
</head>

<body>

<table border = "1">
<tr>
    <th>Face#</th>
    <th>Count</th> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td id="r1">0</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td id="r2">0</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td id="r3">0</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td id="r4">0</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td id="r5">0</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td id="r6">0</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Sum</td>
    <td id="sum">0</td> 
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All answers seem right. Just try the empty defer attribute on the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is running before your HTML loads - placing your script at the bottom of your HTML should fix this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8"; http-equiv="Content-type">
</head>

<body>

<table border = "1">
<tr>
    <th>Face#</th>
    <th>Count</th> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td id="r1">0</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td id="r2">0</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td id="r3">0</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td id="r4">0</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td id="r5">0</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td id="r6">0</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Sum</td>
    <td id="sum">0</td> 
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var dice;

 var one = 0;
 var two = 0; 
 var three = 0;
 var four = 0; 
 var five = 0;
 var six = 0; 

 var i;

 for(i=1; i<=1000; i++) {

 dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
 
 if(dice==1) one++;
 else if(dice==2) two++;
 else if(dice==3) three++;
 else if(dice==4) four++;
 else if(dice==5) five++;
 else six++;

 } //end of for


 //write results to the table
  document.getElementById("r1").innerHTML = one;
 document.getElementById("r2").innerHTML = two;
 document.getElementById("r3").innerHTML = three;
 document.getElementById("r4").innerHTML = four;
 document.getElementById("r5").innerHTML = five;
 document.getElementById("r6").innerHTML = six;
 document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = i;


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the js scripts inside `head` so this line `document.getElementById("r1").innerHTML` will try to get an element from dom even before dom is ready.

Try by removing the script from head and place it near closing body tag like

```
<body>
  //html code

<script>
 //here your js
</script>
</body>
```

Else you can also you `window.onload`

Answer (score 0):

Your script is running before the element is in DOM, hence you are getting the error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

To solve the issue, you can either wrap your code with [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8"; http-equiv="Content-type">
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
     
    var dice;
    var one = 0;
    var two = 0; 
    var three = 0;
    var four = 0; 
    var five = 0;
    var six = 0; 

    var i;

    for(i=1; i<=1000; i++) {

    dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);

    if(dice==1) one++;
    else if(dice==2) two++;
    else if(dice==3) three++;
    else if(dice==4) four++;
    else if(dice==5) five++;
    else six++;

    } //end of for


    //write results to the table
    document.getElementById("r1").innerHTML = one;
    document.getElementById("r2").innerHTML = two;
    document.getElementById("r3").innerHTML = three;
    document.getElementById("r4").innerHTML = four;
    document.getElementById("r5").innerHTML = five;
    document.getElementById("r6").innerHTML = six;
    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = i;
    });

</script>
</head>

<body>

<table border = "1">
<tr>
    <th>Face#</th>
    <th>Count</th> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td id="r1">0</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td id="r2">0</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td id="r3">0</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td id="r4">0</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td id="r5">0</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td id="r6">0</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Sum</td>
    <td id="sum">0</td> 
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

**OR:** Move your *script* at the bottom of the body:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8"; http-equiv="Content-type">

</head>

<body>

<table border = "1">
<tr>
    <th>Face#</th>
    <th>Count</th> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td id="r1">0</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td id="r2">0</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td id="r3">0</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td id="r4">0</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td id="r5">0</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td id="r6">0</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Sum</td>
    <td id="sum">0</td> 
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var dice;

 var one = 0;
 var two = 0; 
 var three = 0;
 var four = 0; 
 var five = 0;
 var six = 0; 

 var i;

 for(i=1; i<=1000; i++) {

 dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
 
 if(dice==1) one++;
 else if(dice==2) two++;
 else if(dice==3) three++;
 else if(dice==4) four++;
 else if(dice==5) five++;
 else six++;

 } //end of for


 //write results to the table
  document.getElementById("r1").innerHTML = one;
 document.getElementById("r2").innerHTML = two;
 document.getElementById("r3").innerHTML = three;
 document.getElementById("r4").innerHTML = four;
 document.getElementById("r5").innerHTML = five;
 document.getElementById("r6").innerHTML = six;
 document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = i;


</script>
</body>
</html>
```